# How to apply staggered grid layout horizontal with different height size

Tags: android, staggeredgridlayoutmanager

So i have to do one layout like on the image, i need to do some scroll list horizontal but with different image size height. It works perfectly with the staggered layout but only at vertical.

This is how i am initiating the adapter:

```
StaggeredGridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
mAdapter = new ColorAdapter(this, list);
mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

The adapter is inflating 2 xml with different types, does anyone know how to do that with the `staggeredlayoutmanager`?

Thank you!!

[image: Staggered layout horizontal]

Comment: https://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/recyclerview-as-staggered-grid-example.html#Example_OfHorizontal_Staggered_GridView_using_RecyclerView_In_Android_Studio